# Word2Vec - to be trained on train data or whole data

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gensim, word2vec, embedding

I wish to create a word2vec model and want to train it on my local data. so, the question is, should I train word2vec model on my whole data or should I split the data into train and test and then train my word2vec model on train data to avoid data leakage as I intend to perform classification task using ml algorithms. I don't want to use pretrained embeddings.

I've trained word2vec on whole dataset but feel like it will lead to data leakage during ml model building

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The word2vec algorithm is an 'unsupervised' method: it works from the raw full data available, *without* you directly telling it desired results, based on peeking at your intended classes.

Thus in some senses, for many uses, it is appropriate to use it as a generic feature-enhancement step that can use *all* available data, even including what would normally be 'held-back' test examples for your separate supervised classification step. Just be sure no part of your texts associates known class labels directly to textual words.

(Similarly: if you have lots of *unlabeled* examples from the same usage-domain, they can often help improve this unsupervised step, even though of course such unlabeled examples can't be supplied to a supervised-classification step.)

Note that the whole reason to "avoid data leakage" is to avoid fooling yourself on evaluations, when you're experimenting & testing multiple-methods against each other. That is: you want your full training/learning pipeline to be a fair *simulation*, and thus trustworthy estimation, of your chosen methods' eventual success on real situations with truly unlabeled data (including new data not even available at experimental-time).

But then, *after& you've chosen a method, when deploying a frozen method to production, you'll often re-train with *all* your labeled examples, because re-estimating the expected performance on the same data no longer needs to be accurate.

You priority, at that later step, is to use *everything* you know to do the best on truly unknown items. The level of success on those new items will be proven in other ways, later. (Perhaps: further manual review/labeling of some subset, or implicit indicators of relative success, or reopening a more-rigorous experimental phase later.)

Now, there could be some situations where the eventual use will regularly be trying to classify new examples whose unlabeled text *wasn't* available at model-creation, and you want a more-accurate estimate's technique in such situations. You *might* want to simulate such cases by using a unsupervised word2vec features that had no peek at bulk unlabeled text.

But conversely, there could be (big-batch) deployment situations where inherently, all the patterns of unlabeled/unknwon texts *are* always available to enhance the unsupervised modeling feature-enrichment. Then, because such data will be regularly be available before the essential classifier-training, including it is *definitively* more-representative of your true usage scenarios.

So overall, training your *unsupervised* features on the bulk without-labels text of 'test' examples is…

- often OK, & practically done without problems, because it's not contaminating the *supervised* step
- but sometimes, peculiarities of what you really want to measure might suggest not to do it – or conversely, strongly suggest it should be done

You might as well try it both ways, to better develop your understanding of its effects, both generally & with your specific data.

(And: if there are massive rather than incremental differences, dig deeper to see why - your data/needs might be a unique situation.)